# objective-c dot notation with square brackets

Tags: objective-c, object, syntax, brackets, cs193p

hi i don't understand this code of course CS193p

```
[[PlayingCard rankStrings][self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
```

where rankString is variable method

```
 + (NSArray *)rankStrings
{
    return @[@"?", @"A", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"J",      @"Q", @"K"];
}
```

self.rank is a getter of random number

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;
```

and self.suit in another variable method

```
 + (NSArray *)validSuits
{
    return @[@"♥️", @"♦️", @"♠️", @"♣️"];
}
```

I insert in my code NSLog to understand the functioning .... I understand that it takes rank from the rankStrings  and concatenates them with the suit .... but I don't understand how! the method appendingString is clear ... but how do you get the values rank ​​from an rankStrings? the [PlayingCard rankStrings] is simple call to a method of variable and NSUInteger rank is a getter

Comment: You're right -- it is confusing, since `[]` is sort of "overloaded".  `[self.rank]` is actually an indexing operation on the array returned from the method call `[PlayingCard rankStrings]`.

Comment: And, of course, `.` here is used to imply a method call to the "getter" for `rank`, not a reference to a field in the structure identified by `self` as would be the case for vanilla C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[PlayingCard rankString]` presumably, returns an array.

`self.rank` is providing an `NSUInteger`.

We can use the square-bracket notation to access an array index as such:

```
myArray[10] // this accesses the object at index 10 of myArray
```

`[PlayingCard rankString][self.rank]` is accessing the object at the `self.rank` index of the array returned by `[PlayingCard rankString]`.

The object at that index is presumably a mutable string, so we're now calling a string method on the returned object.

The code snippet you provided could easily be rewritten as such:

```
NSArray *playingCardArray = [PlayingCard rankString];

NSMutableString *rankString = playingCardArray[self.rank];

[rankString stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
```

Comment: To really do it right replace indexing with `objectAtIndex` and replace the dotted property references with `[]` references.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st line of code you posted is shorthand for the following:

```
[[[PlayingCard rankStrings] objectAtIndex:self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
```

Break it down:

```
NSArray *array = [PlayingCar rankString];
NSString *str = array[self.rank]; // modern syntax for [array objectAtIndex:self.rank]
[str stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
```

And of course `self.rank` is the property syntax that is actually converted to `[self rank]` to call the getter method.